# Embed media option for Fbx export

Tags: export, .fbx

I am currently using blender 2.78. There is no option to embed media while exporting objects as Fbx from blender. Is there a workflow or plugin to export textures along with the object, while exporting as Fbx from blender. Also will the option be available in upcoming blender release.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541 Textures are and should be standalone image files, just save them to disk and open/import them in whatever destination application you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to do that, actually. 
Make sure you're in Blender Render (internal) render mode, though, otherwise it won't work, in my experience.
In Fbx export options, under Main, look all the way down at **"Path mode"**. Set that to **"Copy"** and make sure to **check the little file-in-a-box button** to the right (called "Embed textures").